# The cell delete animation errors in UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete state

Tags: ios, uitableview, animation

Swipe to Delete

The cell in the deleted animation of upward, moved to the right.

code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        RSRecord *ar = [self.audios objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.audios removeObject:ar];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }
}
```

I want to make a SMS delete animation,thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by this way.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    [self.objects removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f
                     animations:^{

                         UIScrollView *internalScrollView = (UIScrollView*)cell.contentView.superview;
                         if([internalScrollView isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]){

                             [internalScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
                         }

                         cell.center = CGPointMake(cell.center.x + cell.bounds.size.width, cell.center.y);
                     //    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         //[cell removeFromSuperview];
                         [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

                     }];
}
}
```

Comment: All animation was wrong. delete button moved to the right  in the deleted animation.